# Using C# reflections to print system information.

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am currently studying C# from scratch and I stumbled upon a topic that was rather difficult to understand .I want to print out the info about the system in the console. I read about reflections in Troelson and decided to give it a try, so I googled and found a windows form project designed for this problem. I tried to make a similar console application but I sort of get an unhandled exception on the part when I try to print. Any tips on how can I make this work or explanations of what have I done wrong ( and I most certainly have) would be very helpful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection; 
namespace MachineInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type propertytype = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation);
            PropertyInfo[] property = propertytype.GetProperties();
            string str; 
            for(int i=0; i<property.Length; i++ )
            {
                str = property[i].ToString();
                Type prop = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation);
                PropertyInfo innerproperty = prop.GetProperty(str);
                Console.WriteLine(innerproperty.ToString()); 
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Main` is not `[STAThread]`, but this is just the beginning. What's the error?

Comment: How are you printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need:

```
for(int i=0; i<property.Length; i++ )
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}",
                property[i].Name, 
                property[i].GetValue(null).ToString());
}
```

`property[i].ToString();` returns the type name which is `PropertyInfo`, and you are trying to get a property named `PropertyInfo` which is not exists.

Also if you want to get static properties don't forget to specify BindingFlags

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
PropertyInfo[] property = propertytype.GetProperties(flags);
```

Comment: Oh thanks, this works,  but can you explain the GetValue part or should I just google ???

Comment: @David_D GetValue method as the name suggests: gets the value of the property

Comment: @Andy T    Sorry, the first time I clicked it said that I need to wait for ten minutes.